# Convert Date and Time with different timezones to timestamp

Tags: java, time, jodatime, java-time

got a little problem in Java: I've got two strings, representing a date (for example "2019-11-10") and a time (for example "01:23:45.123"). Converting those into a UTC timestamp is easy enough, but there is one problem:

The date is given in a local timezone, for example "America/New_York", while the time is given in UTC, so the following information...

`date = "2019-11-10"`, `time="01:23:45.123"` (assuming a local timezone of `"America/New_York"` for the date part)

...would actually be the UTC time `"2019-11-11 01:23:45.123"` (since only this would be a New York date of "2019-11-10").

Does the Java Time API or joda time offer any convenient method to do this conversion while keeping also details like DST, etc. in mind? Is there a (relatively) simple way of doing this at all?

Edit:

Perhaps this was a bit unclear. Let me try to explain it from the other side:

Assuming I have a DateTime x (in UTC) of `"2019-11-11 01:23:45.123"`.

Then I can get the date part y (as seen in "America/New_York") by simply converting x into the appropriate timezone and formatting is accordingly -> `"2019-11-10"`.

I can also get the time part z (as seen in UTC) by simply formatting is accordingly - `"01:23:45.123"`.

Now, assuming I've got y and z - How do I get x?

Edit 2:

I just realized, this will **never** work perfectly. Reason:

UTC "2019-11-04 04:01:00.000" -> US/NY : "2019-11-03 23:01"

UTC "2019-11-03 04:01:00.000" -> US/NY : "2019-11-03 00:01"

So, if I only got the information "date in US/NY" is "2019-11-03" plus "time in UTC" is "04:01:00.000" there are actually two possible solutions and not only one.

Comment: did you checked `ZonedDateTime`

Comment: What does it mean for a date to be given in a time zone?

Comment: I tried to clarify it a bit...

Answer (score 2):

You have to adjust the date to be in the New York time zone which can be done by choosing an arbitrary time. Then convert the time to New York by choosing an arbitrary date. The two can then be merged as they have the same zone. And convert back to UTC

```
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2019-11-10");
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("01:23:45.123");
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");

    ZonedDateTime dateInZone = date.atStartOfDay(zone);
    ZonedDateTime timeInZone = time.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).atDate(date).atZoneSameInstant(zone);
    ZonedDateTime resultNY = dateInZone.with(timeInZone.toLocalTime());
    ZonedDateTime resultUTC = resultNY.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
    System.out.println(resultUTC);
    // 2019-11-11T01:23:45.123Z
```

Comment: While generally true, my main problem is DST. And on those certain days, random time doesn't work because it's actually important... The 99% solution is actually quite easy, true. But unfortunately, the remaining 1% are harder.

Answer (score 1):

A date cannot have a time zone. (Think about it.)

Perhaps what you mean is the first moment of the day for that date as seen in UTC.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2019-11-10" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Adjust that moment to be seen in a time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "01:23:45.123" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt2 = zdt.with( lt ) ;
```

Comment: Yes, normally a time cannot have a timezone. In this case, it does: Let's call the final dateTime x for a moment: In this case, I can get the date part String y by simply converting x to the desired timezone and formatting it apropriately. And I get the time part String z by converting (or keeping) the x in UTC and then formatting it appropriately. The question is: Given y and z, how can I get x?